# return string from a method of return type InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

Though there are other similar posts none solved my issue.
My method is of return type InputStream.
But I need to return "Wrong input" string for a specific condition.
Though I tried 
`return new ByteArrayInputStream("myMessge".getBytes("UTF-8"))`
it returns Object type followed by hashcode.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to tell us which language is this. There are no tags for any language at all.

Comment: @Ermir It is java 1.6. I added another comment below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is Java based on the use of `InputStream`. It seems that you are wanting to use the return type to indicate an error in arguments passed to the method. Instead of returning a special value to indicate an error, I would recommend creating a custom exception. Then wherever you use this method, instead of examining the returned value from the method, you can just catch the exception. You can read more about Exception handling here: [Java Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: yes the scenario is right and this in Java 1.6. Its actually a REST web service. I also tried throwing exception but I get 204 No content instead of Http 200. So I need to return a string saying "wrong input". I tried throwing this exception `throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)` but get 204.

Comment: any ideas on this question?